# Determine the number of days a bill range falls into two different date ranges

Tags: xls, xlsx, xlsm

I am trying to calculate how many days a utility bill falls within two categories (date ranges).i.e. a bill range may be between 16/8/14 - 14/10/14 (total of 60 days incl) and I want to work out how many days fall in the  1/10/2014-31/3/15 season and how many days fall within the 1/4/14-30/9/14 season.  It should be 14 and 46 but I am only getting 13 and 44.  Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Could you show example of the way you are calculating the difference?

Comment: Ingrid, we need more information in order to answer this.  What are you currently trying?  How is your data arranged?

Comment: In columns A1, B1, C1 I have the following information (Season, Start, Finish) : Summer, 1/10/14, 31/3/15. In Rows A2, B2, C3 I have Winter, 1/4/15, 30/9/15. In rows A3, B3, C3 I have Summer, 1/10/15, 31/3/16.  This dictates the season ranges.  Then I need to calculate if my bill comes in and spans across two seasons i.e. the bill is from 6/8/15-20/3/16...what formula do I use to show how many days is the bill in the Summer season and how many in the Winter season?